# Using FormData in servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am having formData that contains a file

Like :

```
  var files = document.getElementById("uploadfile").files;
  /* Create a FormData instance */
  var formData = new FormData();
  /* Add the file */ 
  var file = files[0];
  alert(file.name);
  formData.append('uploadfile', file, file.name);
  client.open("POST", "fileupload?q="+uploadfile,true);
  client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
  client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */
```

Now i want to use this form data in my servlet fileupload.How to use it their ?Please help.

Comment: Buddy please use google and get back one you have tried and stuck in some point.

Comment: @APaul I googled it.But didnt get what i required thats why posted it here

Comment: Please google using "jquery file upload using servlet". And check if the results help you !!

Comment: 1. Don't set the content-type header. 2. Handle it like any other file upload. 3. Is `uploadfile` defined aywhere?

Comment: @APaul No the results their are different from my question.could you please help here?

Comment: @Musa which uploadfile is defined?I didnt get you

Comment: There is only one `uploadfile` identifier in your code. `"fileupload?q="+uploadfile`

Comment: @Musa Oh i was just testing it.I didnt used that q parameter anywhere in my servlet.So not a trouble.Actually I was thinking how to send these files at server end

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example how I handled it in my project. I used doPost function to get it.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

Do whatever you want with that item.

}
```

Comment: It gives an exception that org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/2599879 this answer also explains in detail how to handle file upload. You can find also necessary jar links in the answer which are commons-fileupload.jar and commons-io.jar